# Where is the __cpuid_count function found on osx in it's shared library?

Tags: c, macos, nm

I'd like to know where the function `__cpuid_count` is on osx. I'm assuming that it's in `libc` but running:

```
nm -g /usr/lib/libc.dylib
```

or

```
nm -g /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Does not list the function in the outputs. Is there a better way to locate where it is?

Comment: `__cpuid_count` is not a standard C function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find a `__cpuid_count` function because there isn't one. It's defined as a macro that expands to inline assembly in `cpuid.h`.